# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI when trying to open downloaded image

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-11

I can't open image downloaded with `DownloadManager` when clicking on a notification.

This is how it's reproducible:
I download an image from network using `DownloadManager`.
Then when I click on Notification about this download and OS shows me a dialog where I can choose Application to open downloaded image, but when I pick any application, none of them work.
For example, when opening with Google Photos I see this error in Logcat.

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/12322
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.query(DownloadProvider.java:1298)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1379)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1475)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:278)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

This reproduces on Android 11, on previous version everything works well.
When checking the filesystem the image is there in `Downloads` folder

I'm using this code for downloading images

```
val downloadService: DownloadManager = activity.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as val downloadService: DownloadManager = activity.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
downloadService.enqueue(DownloadManager.Request(attachment.getAttachmentUri())
        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setDescription("Downloading attachments")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title)
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
)
```

Tested on **Pixel3a** Android 11
targetSdkVersion 30
compileSdkVersion 30

Comment: `content://downloads/public_downloads/12322` That is no valid content scheme as the provider is missing. Who constructed this string value?

Comment: Strange story..

Comment: This URI was constructed by Download Manager

Comment: What is your environment? Build tools/device vendor/target API/etc. On an emulator with the latest version the downloaded file uri is `content://downloads/all_downloads/5`

Comment: @blackapps: "the provider is missing" -- if by "provider" you mean "authority", the authority is `downloads`. Some of the really old system providers do not use namespaces.

Comment: You are assuming that a `Uri` returned to *your app* via `DownloadManager` is usable by *every other app on the device*. That is not a safe assumption, particularly on Android 10 and higher. And `DownloadManager` will be increasingly weird in the world of scoped storage, since external storage access is per-app and the downloads provider is a different app from yours. If you have filesystem access to the downloaded file, use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to make it available to other apps.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare. I had realised later that it had confused me.. Further i think OP cannot use a FileProvider at clicking the notification. OP stands helpless.

Comment: Thank @CommonsWare for clarification, but the point is that I'm not handling `Uri`.
When I enqueue download, `DownloadManager` shows a notification to the user, and when taping on this notification system shows a popup where I can choose with which App to open this intent. 
I'm wondering if I can alter this behavior somehow.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem testing on Pixel 3 XL emulator running api 30. The Photos app gladly shows the downloaded file. Try to create a new emulator.

Comment: `I'm wondering if I can alter this behavior somehow.` Yes. You can do without that notification and use a broadcast receiver to get informd when download is done. Then use a FileProvider and ACTION_VIEW. But... all should not be necessaray.

Comment: Thank I'll consider this option.
And I'm testing on Pixel 3a physical device

Comment: "DownloadManager shows a notification to the user, and when taping on this notification system shows a popup where I can choose with which App to open this intent" -- oh, sorry, I didn't realize this was a `DownloadManager`-supplied notification. That feels like a bug in Android. Other than either downloading the content yourself, or at least showing the notification yourself, I do not know of a solution. I have not used `DownloadManager` in years, so there may be options that I am forgetting, though.

Comment: `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` Try `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` or yet other ones as that has a different provider... oh sorry .. authority.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I'll try your suggestions